# .NET application trying to access crl.verisign.net

Tags: .net, tcp

I have a number of internal .NET applications from our vendor that take forever to startup.  Some of their services take up to 1.5 minutes to start.  Upon further investigation, I noticed that under Process Explorer's TCP/IP tab, I see the application trying to make outbound connections to crl.verisign.net.  Unfortunately, most of our production servers do not have internet access!  I believe they are using authenticode which is significantly impacting their applications load time.

Any idea how to disable this "feature"?

The vendor has been having me change the default SCM wait time of 30 seconds to a much higher value to pervent the timeout and the service from stating.

Comment: I've figured out that if I create my own app.config file and add the following, I elimiante this issue and application starts in 2-3 seconds. 

<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also try adding a bogus entry in your Hosts File (%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)  for "crl.verisign.net" pointing to localhost.

Like so:

```
127.0.0.1 crl.verisign.net
```

This is what you typically do for the same reason (production server not having internet access) when .NET applications try to contact "crl.microsoft.com".

Comment: This is what I had initially tried but it wasn't working.  Perhaps it was cached.  I didn't try rebooting or anything but I know it wasn't picking up the change.

Comment: How would I authenticode a .NET WinForm application, if I wanted to?

Comment: I have no idea, you should probably post a new question.